# Why do I get dark horizontal lines (stripes or bands) in bad lighting with my Fuji X-T1?

Tags: artifacts, fujifilm

Can anyone explain why I get these lines when taking photos in bad/weak lighting? Here are some photos.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Could you please include what settings you used, and also (if you know/can remember) what type of lighting was being used.

Comment: Related: [How can one correct intensity flicker due to AC line frequency?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59454/how-can-one-correct-intensity-flicker-due-to-ac-line-frequency/) This is assuming it's taken under fluorescent lighting, but the pattern is pretty distinctive.

Comment: And also [What causes the lines in these photos of a fluorescent tube?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54532/what-causes-the-lines-in-these-photos-of-a-fluorescent-tube)

Comment: In particular, we want to know a) what your shutter speed was, b) if the room was lit with flourescent lights, and c) if your camera was in an electronic shutter or silent shooting mode.

Comment: Was your exposure time around 1/10s ? I can measure it by counting the number of bands and supposing that your light is flickering at 60Hz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the lines in these photos of a fluorescent tube?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54532/what-causes-the-lines-in-these-photos-of-a-fluorescent-tube)

Answer (score 13):

These lines are very likely there because of the frequency at which your light flickers. This is most notably the case with fluorescent lighting or led lighting, especially when you dim the light. Led are dimmed by switching them on/off rapidly. The dimmer the light the longer the off periods which our cameras capture easily (and not only the X-T1)

Another possible explanation is that you used the electronic shutter; which can also cause interferences with certain light frequency.

You will find this issue well documented by the guys photographing performance on stage with led lighting; especially on performances with low lighting budget.

Hope this helps

Comment: This explains. I also have this issue and Led lighting all around the house. Next I have the idea that this effect is stronger when using the electronic shutter of the X-T1.

Comment: Yes true. Its very common. I get the same dark bars with my Fuji X-E2S when shot using ES in fluorescent light.

Comment: had the same problem with the Sony 7Rii indoors. I do have LED lights that are on a dimmer system.

Comment: With X-T1 I observed those stripes only with LED light an electroic shutter. With manual shutter they are gone.

Comment: I got those same lines with an A7RII at a medium venue rock concert and I'm thinking it's the electronic shutter as well.

Comment: I have noticed this behavior not just after taking the photo, but also just while pointing the camera at some very bright light. But the stripes travel side to side at constant speed. Is it the same phenomenon?